# Unable to RegisterStartupScript from an execution other than Page_Load

Tags: asp.net, scriptmanager, clientscriptmanager

I use ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScrit from Page_Load and it works perfect.

When I move the same line to the Page_Unload event, it doesn't work; the script is not registered.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Why would you be trying to register a startup script when the page is unloading?

Comment: I want to enter scripts according to what happens during the Button_Click etc. events.
I wouldn't really care to do it in another way, but it has to be done outside the Page_Load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Page_Unload event is called after the page is created and the html is outputted. The event is meant to be used to clean up any resources that must be freed by the page.

Why are you calling ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript here?

EDIT:
[See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) for an overview over the page life cycle of an ASP.Net page. It should help you to determine where to place your code. Most likely the last time you can call ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript is at the Page_PreRender event.

Comment: I want to enter scripts according to what happens during the Button_Click etc. events.

Comment: PreRender is after the control events have been handled, so you can probably run your code there

Comment: This is the answer.
Please update your original answer, and I will mark it.